# with out dropdown Autocomplete + static value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have some name like (php,java,.net,ios,android) want to make autocomplete using jquery or ajax with own css with out dorpdown. i have to show result with link  in p tag.

Comment: Let me understand this. Would you like with `ul`  and `li`? It wont be a dropdown list but unordered list if thats fine?

Comment: yes,no i don't want with ul and li .it should be show in p tag like. <input type="text" id="xyz"><pid="show"></p>

Comment: Hi pritesh,could you please get me ans.